# Cassandra unable to query sum of rows from a table

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cql

I am using Cassandra database for capturing and saving a simple network sniffer data, but because the number of rows in the table is greater than 20M+ rows, it is unable to run any aggregate function such as `sum` or `count`.

Following is my table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE db.uinfo (
    id timeuuid,
    created timestamp,
    dst_ip text,
    dst_mac text,
    dst_port int,
    protocol int,
    src_ip text,
    src_mac text,
    src_port int,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, created)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (created ASC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

Now when I run the query(with or without limit):

```
select src_ip, sum(data) as total from db.uinfo;
```

It throws me the following error:

```
OperationTimedOut: errors={'127.0.0.1': 'Client request timeout. See Session.execute[_async](timeout)'}, last_host=127.0.0.1
```

Any chance any of you good people could help me do the same? I have tried changing the timeouts in the `cqlshrc` and `cassandra.yaml` respectively. I have even tried starting the cqlsh using:

`cqlsh  --connect-timeout=120 --request-timeout=120`.

I am using `[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.4 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]`

Answer (score 2):

This kind of queries won't work with Cassandra when you have relatively big data in it - such kind of queries requires the scanning of the whole database, and reading all data in it. Cassandra is great when you know the partition that you want to hit, and as such, send query only to individual servers where they could be processed very effectively. So aggregation functions work best only within partition.

If you need this kind of queries done - the common suggestion is to use Spark to read data in parallel, and perform aggregations. You can do this using [Spark Cassandra Connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/tree/master/doc), but it will be slower than usual queries - maybe dozens of seconds, or even minutes, depending on the size of data, hardware for Spark jobs, etc.

If you need this kind of queries performed very often, then you need to look to other technologies, but it's hard to say who will perform well in such situation.